plot_surface show wrong values
I am using matplotlib.pyplot plot_surface to plot cone_like 3D surface from noisy array data, and I found there are some added error points if the cone's vertex center region is open, but these error points disappeared if the vertex center region filled.
Does anyone know how to avoid these artificial noise points?
Using debug I checked the array data, and it has no error. I expect a good shaped cone with opened and noisy top. But the plot_surface added some noisy points in front of the cone
